# Clearing apt-cache policy version table to prevent the installation of newer versions

Tags: apt, version, cuda

I am trying to install a specific package , CUDA for Nvidia to be exact. I followed the steps in their developer guide and my question is not about CUDA specifically. When I try to install it with APT normally it tries to install the latest version at this time which is 11.6. The guide I followed, however, is for version 11.4 which is compatible with my current kernel version. I downloaded the `deb` package for the 11.4 version manually, installed it with `dpkg`, and did a `sudo apt update` before trying to `sudo apt install cuda`. I was not sure why it tries to install version 11.6 while the `deb` package I installed is for 11.4 until I saw the output of `apt-cache policy cuda`:

```bsh
cuda:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 11.6.2-1
  Version table:
     11.6.2-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.6.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.6.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.5.2-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages

     11.5.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.5.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages

     11.4.4-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
        600 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-4-local  Packages
     11.4.3-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.4.2-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.4.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.4.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.3.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.3.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.2.2-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.2.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.2.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.1.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.1.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.0.3-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.0.2-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
```

The version I installed shows indeed in the `var` directory but I have a lot of other versions in the version table. I know I can install the specific version I want using `sudo apt insatll cuda=11.4.4-1` but I am afraid if someone else does an upgrade that it will auto upgrade breaking my installation as I share the machine.

My question is: will running `sudo apt upgrade` after installing the specific CUDA version I want (version 11.4) update it to the latest version in the version table (version 11.6)? If yes, how can I prevent that? Is there any way I can clear the version table to remove the links shown above? I think I may have added them by mistake when I was trying the network installed for CUDA but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold the package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold cuda
```

man apt-mark:

```
   hold
       hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being
       automatically installed, upgraded or removed.
```